Docker build using secrets
I am trying to inject a azure variable into a docker file env but I am getting an error indicating that the token is not valid. When I hardcode the token, it works fine.
# 1. Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN \
    SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN)


# 2. Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN="{{NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN}}"
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_LOGGING_ENABLED="{{NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_LOGGING_ENABLED}}"
ENV SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN="{{SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN}}"

RUN yarn build

# 3. Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
ENV USE_HTTPS=true

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/next-i18next.config.js ./next-i18next.config.js

RUN ["chmod", "755", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

The token is stored as a azure secret variable. Here is the build pipeline command to inject.
 - script: 
   SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN docker buildx build -f
   dockerfile.prod --secret id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN -t $(IMAGE_ID)
   --progress plain .

   displayName: 'docker build'
   env:
     SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: $(SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN)

It feels like the token is not encrypted at all. Anyone got an answer?

It looks like you're only using the secret value in the RUN yarn build step.  If that's the case, you need the --mount=type=secret option in that specific RUN line, and nowhere else.  You do not need to set the variable as an ENV.
FROM node:20-alpine AS base
# empty

FROM base AS builder
...
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN \
  SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN) \
  yarn build

Remember that anything built into your image is fairly easily extracted.  If the token is being built into your browser-based application, it may be there in plain text in the final application, and it may be served on the public Internet that way.  This also may be required for your front-end application to interact with the external service.
If that's accepable (or required) then it may be more straightforward to just pass the variable as a ARG.  This will automatically be visible in the environment to RUN instructions, and if it's present in the final image then it will be accessible there.
ARG SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN
RUN yarn build

docker buildx build \
  -f dockerfile.prod \
  --build-arg SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN=... \
  -t $(IMAGE_ID) \
  --progress plain \
  .


Thank you for the instructions. Yes, the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN is only to be used during the build process to upload the source maps hence I do not want to use passing arg as it might bake into the image.
Following your instructions and updates to my docker file, I got a 401. I feel that the token is not being read correctly. I am trying to log what is being passed as SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN via the bash.
I tried using RUN echo cat /run/secrets/SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN but nothing came up. I assume it is really a secret

The /run/secrets/... file only exists in the specific RUN command with the --mount=type=secret option.  If you try to set an environment variable in that RUN command, it gets lost at the end of the RUN command.

I am still getting an authorised error. The dockerfile work correctly locally when i pass the secret from a file like this
docker build -f dockerfile.prod --secret id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,src=secrets -t ui:with-secrets .
but with azure pipeline, it looks like it does not read it correctly
i am storing the auth_token as secret variable so is my azure command correct
docker buildx build -f
   dockerfile.prod --secret id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN -t $(IMAGE_ID)
   --progress plain . 
   env:
     SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: $(SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN)


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables
did some reading and it looks correct mapping the value as env

i got it working. Use @DavidMaze docker file update and the azure pipeline script should be
docker buildx build -f    dockerfile.prod --secret id=SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN -t $(IMAGE_ID)    --progress plain .      
pass the secret variable as env.
